CNN matrices shape for time series data processing
I would like to ask you for advice regarding CNNs for analysing 60000x16 data (single input) - time series records from 16 channels. I did some research on this and my initial idea was to use CNN with CONV2D layers with input size equal to mentioned above.
First I'd like to ask for general advice of choosing kernel size - there are mixed opinions across the internet - nonsquare kernel is unpopular choice (Is it?), but for data like this seems reasonable.
It is also often said that filter size of 200 x 8 is not likely to work because of the size difference and the fact that features choice in CNNs shouldn't be mixed between different channels.
On the other hand when analysing my records I can see that most of changes in data are noticeable after first ~2000 samples and going through every 10 samples seems just pointless. I am also sure that some relation exists between recorded channels.
I'd be glad to get any guidance as I'm new to the topic of NN. Thanks in advance  :)
